# Retrieve CSV values as single $variables

Tags: php, ajax, post, csv

I'm trying to make this:

```
174,myfilename.jpg
```

Into this on the php post process page:

```
$id = 174
$filename = myfilename.jpg
```

The problem is that **id=174,myfilename.jpg**

The way that I get my values is using an ajax post function.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="<?php echo $id ;?>,<?php echo $filename;?>" onclick="deleteFile(id,name)" ><img border="0" src="images/close.png"></a>


function deleteFile(id,name) {

if (confirm("..."))
{

var txt = $.ajax({
url: 'deletefile.php',
async: true,
type:'POST',
data:({
id:id,
lid: <?php echo $_GET['id'];?>
}) 
}).success;
$('.successRemoveFile').slideDown('slow');
//setTimeout(function(){ window.top.location.reload();}, 2000);
}

}
```

Thanks in advance.
jonny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sounds like [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`list`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) are what you're looking for:

```
list($id, $filename) = explode(",", $_POST['id']);
```

Comment: hi, would i now have a value $id and $filename to work with. It seems to not work on the php delete page

Comment: yes, this is how it works. maybe you're submitting a wrong or empty value? please try to `var_dump` the involved variables and see if they contain what you're expecting.

Comment: you are a genius! i now know somethign else about php. Never knew about the list() command. THANK YOU